# Simulink: draw only the graphic marker without image/video

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, simulink, markers, matlab-cvst

Usually i use 'Draw Markers' block (Computer Vision System tb) when i have to draw a marker on an image or video and i send it to a 'Video Display' block. Is there a way to send only the marker (as on a transparent background) ?
I tried it with sum/subtract block:
(Image + Marker) - Image ;
But i would like to avoid that further algebraic calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your background and what value of background you can use to indicate transparency. In the case of "(Image + Marker) - Image" you are basically defining your background as zero. You can simply start with an image of all zeros and use "Draw Markers" on it. That should give you the same results.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So, how can i define a zero-opacity background that i can send (transparentBackground + Marker) signal to, for example, a see-trough display ? If i follow your suggestion there will be a black background around the marker, is it?

Comment: Yes, there will be a black background. Transparency is some times done by marking one specific value in the image matrix as the marker for transparency. "Video Display" block does not support displaying such transparency.

Comment: I hope i don't go off topic but i need to send only the marker to a see-through display without any background for an augmented reality application. Can i use an other full screen visualizator as sink block?

Comment: How does your see-through display work. What format it needs as input to make some pixels transparent? Does it mark a specific value of a pixel as transparent or does it use images with color maps? You need to model that in Simulink. It does not matter what you see with Video Display block in this case.

Comment: It works as a hdmi display (what i see in pc integrated display it shows), so i don't know what is its transparent as pixel value and i still know it uses images with a color map. Yes i need to model that in simulink. It would be better it use a specific pixel-value (in double, uint8, or other datatype) as transparent but I don't know how to find out.